# PHP JSON can't echo values, always returning an array?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I have started messing around with Json, with ajax recently.

I have this javascript code:

```
var json = {
    "test": [{
        "number":1,
        "char":"hey",
        "bool":true
    }]
};
$.ajax({
    url: "json.php",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {json: JSON.stringify(json)},
    success: function(res) {
        $("#box").html(res);
    }
});
```

A few minutes ago, this code worked absolutely fine, when I did `echo $json['test']['number'];` it returned `1`.

But now this won't work at all, it says that 'json' index is UNDEFINED , therefore I tried using `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",` which does work, but I can't get the array items at all.

If I won't pass a true parameter in the `json_decode()` function, I will receive the following error:

```
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

If I will do it I will not get the data, but the response will say "Array".

And that's what I am *echoing*:

```
$json = $_POST['json'];
$json = json_decode($json, true);
echo $json['test'][0];
```

And that is my var_dump of `$json`:

```
array(1) {
  ["test"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["number"]=>
      int(1)
      ["char"]=>
      string(3) "hey"
      ["bool"]=>
      bool(true)
    }
  }
}
```

Why is it doing that? why can't I get the values out of it without it returning an Array?

Comment: *"`var json =`"* **That's not JSON**, that's a JavaScript object initializer. JSON is a textual, non-code, data notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this:

```
var json = {
    "test": [{
        "number":1,
        "char":"hey",
        "bool":true
    }]
};
```

Your PHP code

```
$json['test']['number'];
```

would have **only** worked in the first place if `test` was *not* an array. The above, in JavaScript, would look like:

```
json.test.number;
```

But `test` is an `Array`; it has no `number` property. In JavaScript, this would be the correct way to find the `number`:

```
json.test[0].number;
```

You need to do the same in PHP:

```
$json['test'][0]['number'];
```

Comment: I get it now, making sense now.